# How to handle an all-in from the opponent on the flop?

Tags: all-in

Here's the specific scenario I ran into yesterday:

It's a live 1/2 game, I have pocket kings UTG+2. UTG+3 raises to $15, everyone folds to me, I raise to $45. He calls. The flop comes 37Tr. I check to him and he shoves. I call and he shows TT. He flopped a set of tens.

In hindsight, it's obvious that he flopped a monster hand and the correct move was to fold since all I had was top pair at the end of the day. In my experience, an all-in without prior betting on a dry board usually indicates a monster hand. I'd say 90% of the time I made this type of call, it turned out to be a set or two pair.

On the other hand, I did beat a few hands in his range such as QQ, JJ, AT. How would you handle this scenario?

Comment: How did +3 act before you in +2?  What are the effective stack sizes?  What is your history with this villain?

Comment: You mean in prior hands? He was essentially a maniac. One time he shoved prefop without looking at his cards. Another time he played carefully. Very unpredictable. Both our stacks were roughly $200.